# HTML5 Video tag show blank page and not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I am trying to make video slider using **slick slider**, why playsinline not work in `safari`.

```
<div id="videoSlider">
   <video class="video" webkit-playsinline playsinline>
      <source src="/assets/video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <video class="video" webkit-playsinline playsinline >
      <source src="/assets/video/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <video class="video" webkit-playsinline playsinline >
      <source src="/assets/video/3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, autoplay executes only if the video doesn’t contain an audio track, or if the video element includes the muted attribute.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_jfor_safari

Comment: I control autoplay with javascript because I am trying to make video slider using slick slider. Also I add autoplay and muted but not working in safari.